# C# - Name the Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Using Fluent Interface design [here](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/07/creating-fluent-interface-in-c-for.html)

if i call something  like

```
 dog.Train("Running").Train("Eating").Do("Running").Do("Eating");
```

what is the name of this pattern ? is it chain-of-responsibility or there any specific design pattern name associated with it?

Comment: I think it is called 'Fluent Interfaces' as you rightly state in the first line. or Method Chaining. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html - Also not sure if it qualifies as a design pattern

Comment: It looks to be the same pattern used by jQuery.  No idea of the name though.

Comment: Btw, it's a terrible design for your example. Why would Dog.Train() method return a Dog instance? And is it the same Dog instance or a diferent Dog instance? :-)

Comment: @Franci  Your question is good.Let us leave that for a moment,because i took the example from the article (link is given),just i wanted to know the pattern name. :)

Comment: @nettguy - that' why it's a comment, 'cause it's orthogonal to your question... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Method chaining](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html)

EDIT:

From [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

> a fluent interface (as first coined by
>   Eric Evans and Martin Fowler) is a way
>   of implementing an object oriented API
>   in a way that aims to provide for more
>   readable code.
>
> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the  instruction context of a subsequent call (but a fluent interface entails more than just  method chaining).

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical about the relationship between "chaining" and "readability". I personally love chaining, because it's cool, and produces few lines of code... but is it really more readable when you have a big chain of events, than a sequence of operations where it's clearly defined what operation is being performed on what?

Comment: @Mark: I agree. Method chaining isn't always more readable. I think readable method chaining is a part of the fluent interface style.

Comment: The point of method chaining (as used above) is that you can effectively use the language and the chained methods to implement a mini language, with the method calls taking the place of a lexer/parser.  The other type of method chaining (`Foo.GetBar().GetBaz().GetQux().DoSomething()`) is often called a trainwreck, and is about as disastrous :)

Answer (score 2):

Chain of responsibility is more of a multiple class/object level pattern, where messages are passed down a hierarchy of objects, and each object can decide whether or not it can deal with the message or pass it on.

I think the pattern you show here is basically just a "Fluent Interface," like you said.

Comment: Just wanted to know, Fluent interface itself is a design pattern or it is a technique?

Comment: I feel this is just a way to extend the concept of Method Chaining to the Interface level. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it's really a "pattern."  It's more of an idiom.

At any rate, I'd call it either a fluent interface, or an internal Domain Specific Language.